# Moving host from windows 2008 to windows 2022

Tags: ftp, network-share, iis-7.5, hosting

I am trying to change the host of my website. (Windows 2008 IIS moving to Windows 2022). We are stuck with IIS cause the site runs in classic asp.

I need to move 3.5 million files from one remote Host to another. Ideally with some kind of comparison, so when we are ready to change the DNS. We can quickly compare the old server to the new and copy across any new files that have been added to the site since we did the bulk copy.

I have been trying with FreeFileSync - A multithreaded FTP style Client. This works for a bit and then dies. It seems to very quickly do stuff, and then after a certain amount of files stops. And then connection is either intermittent, impossible or very slow.

I believe something in our network path, possible some kind of perimeter firewall with out current host is stopping the transfer via FTP. I think its likely that its our datacentre deciding that something dodgy is going on, and blocking the path.

How else could we manage to transfer that many files, without upsetting the perimeter firewall, and without asking the datacentre to copy everything on a disk.

My Network Friend tonight suggested using an SMB connection and doing a robocopy...

Any feedback much appreciated.

Thanks.

FreeFileSync - Works locally very well. E.g. Between our self managed dev server, and new Live server.

Not when we try and do the same thing on our current Live server, and new live server.

Comment: "to copy everything on a disk" is in fact a better way to go.